# Como eu passo um valor da View para o Controller no asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Eu quero passar da View

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <th>Serviço</th>
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>Feito</th>
</tr>
@{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.servico)
    {
<tr>
    <td>@item.Servico</td>
    <td>@item.Data</td>
    <td>@item.Feito</td>
    <td>Editar</td>
    <td>
        <form action="/Tarefas/Remover" method="post">
            @{
                var tarefa = item;
             }
            <input type="submit" value="Excluir" />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
    }
}
```

Para o controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Remover(Tarefa tarefa)
{
    using (var item = new AgendaDBContext())
    {
        item.Servicos.Remove(tarefa);
        item.SaveChanges();

    }
    return View("Lista");
}
```

Comment: Já tentou passando somente o controller na Action? `<form action="/Tarefas" method="post">`

Comment: <form action="/Tarefas/Remover" method="post">

Eu to passando por post, só não sei como passar o objeto

Comment: Seus campos precisam estar dentro do form e o atributo `name` dos campos precisam ser os mesmos nomes das propriedades que se referem a sua model `Tarefa`.

Comment: Inclua a estrutura da entidade `Tarefa` em sua pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVIDO
* Só não estou com dúvidas se isso seria uma má pratica, estou enviando a id para controller criando uma nova instancia de tarefa e associando a ela uma id e enviado ao entity para excluir.

Criar uma nova instância é uma má pratica ?

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <th>Serviço</th>
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>Feito</th>
</tr>
@{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.servico)
    {
<tr>
    <td>@item.Servico</td>
    <td>@item.Data</td>
    <td>@item.Feito</td>
    <td>Editar</td>
    <td>
        <form action="/Tarefas/Remover" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.Id" />
            <input type="submit" value="Excluir" />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
            }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Remover(int id)
    {            
        using (var item = new AgendaDBContext())
        {
            Tarefa tarefa = new Tarefa();
            tarefa.Id = id;
            item.Servicos.Remove(tarefa);
            item.SaveChanges();

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Lista", "Tarefas");
    }
```

Comment: funciona, o hidden field é o que um `<asp for=...` poderia renderizar para o caso ou poderia ser o próprio botão por exemplo... a prática não é das melhores, não faz sentido ter um form por linha. com outras abordagens e estrutura, você consegue implementar essa funcionalidade de forma mais simples e com mais recursos, como por exemplo a opção de multipla seleção para a remoção